# Получение идентификатора в iOS 7 (UDID, OpenUDID, UUID, и т.п)

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

В приложении требуется получение идентификатора, но так как `UDID` запретили использовать еще в `iOS 6`, я вынужден спрашивать вас :C. Что может заменить `UDID`?

Пробовал `NSUUID`

```
NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID]
UUIDString];
```

Меняется после переустановки приложения.

Пробовал `"IDFV" Identifier for Vendor`:

```
NSString *idfv = [[[UIDevice
currentDevice] identifierForVendor]
UUIDString];
```

Но он тоже меняется (и не понятно почему, он бывает снова возвращает старый идентификатор).

Так же хотел попробовать `Advertiser Identifier`, но `ASIdentifierManager` и `advertisingIdentifier` не распознается xCode. Программа уже готова для обновления в `xCode` и в `iTunesConnect`, уже перед заливкой в `iTunes` заметил что идентификатор менялся. Пожалуйста подскажите уже готовым решением, до 18:00 планирую залить в `iTunes`. Заранее большое спасибо).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дак это UIID на то и UIID - он должен быть разным каждую долю сикунды во всем мире один такой. 
Если вы хотите не изменяемый UIID, то раньше, да использовали идентификатор устройства. В связи с чем рекламщики злоупотребляли сбором данной информации. И теперь эта функция контралируется пользователем.
На сегодняший день мы вышли из данной ситуации зпросом MAC адреса GSM/Wi-Fi подулей, после хеша md5-подобной функции мы получили UID.

Вот пример реализации:

```
@implementation TCMacAddress

+ (NSString *)getMacAddress
{
    int                 mgmtInfoBase[6];
    char                *msgBuffer = NULL;
    size_t              length;
    unsigned char       macAddress[6];
    struct if_msghdr    *interfaceMsgStruct;
    struct sockaddr_dl  *socketStruct;
    NSString            *errorFlag = NULL;

    // Setup the management Information Base (mib)
    mgmtInfoBase[0] = CTL_NET;        // Request network subsystem
    mgmtInfoBase[1] = AF_ROUTE;       // Routing table info
    mgmtInfoBase[2] = 0;
    mgmtInfoBase[3] = AF_LINK;        // Request link layer information
    mgmtInfoBase[4] = NET_RT_IFLIST;  // Request all configured interfaces

    // With all configured interfaces requested, get handle index
    if ((mgmtInfoBase[5] = if_nametoindex("en0")) == 0)
        errorFlag = @"if_nametoindex failure";
    else
    {
        // Get the size of the data available (store in len)
        if (sysctl(mgmtInfoBase, 6, NULL, &length, NULL, 0) < 0)
            errorFlag = @"sysctl mgmtInfoBase failure";
        else
        {
            // Alloc memory based on above call
            if ((msgBuffer = malloc(length)) == NULL)
                errorFlag = @"buffer allocation failure";
            else
            {
                // Get system information, store in buffer
                if (sysctl(mgmtInfoBase, 6, msgBuffer, &length, NULL, 0) < 0)
                    errorFlag = @"sysctl msgBuffer failure";
            }
        }
    }
    // Befor going any further...
    if (errorFlag != NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorFlag);
        return errorFlag;
    }
    // Map msgbuffer to interface message structure
    interfaceMsgStruct = (struct if_msghdr *) msgBuffer;
    // Map to link-level socket structure
    socketStruct = (struct sockaddr_dl *) (interfaceMsgStruct + 1);
    // Copy link layer address data in socket structure to an array
    memcpy(&macAddress, socketStruct->sdl_data + socketStruct->sdl_nlen, 6);
    // Read from char array into a string object, into traditional Mac address format
    NSString *macAddressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
                                  macAddress[0], macAddress[1], macAddress[2],
                                  macAddress[3], macAddress[4], macAddress[5]];
    //NSLog(@"Mac Address: %@", macAddressString);
    // Release the buffer memory
    free(msgBuffer);
    return macAddressString;
}

@end
```

Comment: mgmtInfoBase[0] = CTL_NET;       
mgmtInfoBase[1] = AF_ROUTE;       
mgmtInfoBase[3] = AF_LINK;        
mgmtInfoBase[4] = NET_RT_IFLIST;  

Ругается на них, мол использование не объявленного идентификатора) 
"use of undeclared identifier"

Также ошибки -
http://f3.s.qip.ru/MQ9HpEaH.png
(Извиняюсь что в скрине, но мне не удалось скопировать текст)

TCMacAddress.m установил как "TCMacAddress : UIResponder".

В чем проблема)?

Comment: ой выж наверное в XCode кодите ^_^
Попробуйте импорты прописать:
```
#import <sys/socket.h>
#import <sys/sysctl.h>
#import <net/if.h>
#import <net/if_dl.h>
```

Comment: Ой не знанием мадчасти папахивает:

     NSString *macAddress = [TCMacAddress getMacAddress];

Comment: Благодарю)

Comment: Да не за что ;) Просто такие сложные вопросы ), а мадчасть не знаем )

Comment: Пришлось удалить два комментария т.к. был лимит :D, финальный вопрос, медчасть не знаем потому что пишу игры (JS - Unity3D):C, но есть один проект на Objective-C, и так - нубо-вопрос:
http://f3.s.qip.ru/MQ9HpEaU.png
Портирую в ВьюКонтроллер.m: #imoprt "TCMacAddress.h", тем самым распознаю TCMacAddress, но она не понимает что такое getMacAddress, если буду портировать "TCMacAddress.m", ошибки в коде не будет, но при компиляции появится. Как правильно будет сделать?

Comment: В TCMacAddress.h содержимое такого вида?

   @interface TCMacAddress : NSObject
    + (NSString *)getMacAddress;
   @end

Если нет, то отстаньте от меня.

Comment: Вот теперь всё норма, но как я понял, этот способ не подходит для iOS 7, на iOS 7 будет возвращаться - 02:00:00:00:00:00, так что единственная надежда на import "UIDevice+Identifier.h" :C Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Отслеживать устройства запрещено apple. Можете отслеживать пользователей например по их логину но для этого в вашем приложении это должно как-то быть реализовано. Отлеживать сами устройства у вас не получится.

Comment: Как же это печально.. :C

Comment: я тоже в свое время очень сильно обломался.

Comment: OpenUDID тоже запрещен? Его вроде можно как-то получить...

Comment: https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID

Comment: он меняется?

Comment: да. https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID/issues/53

Comment: беда печаль. Ну будь что будет )